# List sections with books associated with them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm fairly new to ruby on rails and this has been kind of an interesting problem since this seems easy to implement in other languages but I don't know how to tackle it in this one. There was a similar post to this but it had two separate models which I would like to avoid.

This is my end goal:

**Section Name**

- Book A, author
- Book B, author

**Section Name**

- Book C, author
- Book D, author

Ideally, I'd like to have books be one model, so my model looks like this:

**Book Model**

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
   validates :section, :title, :author, presence: true
```

**Book Controller**

```
def index
   @books = Book.all
```

I'm assuming I would need some sort of view that has it list it like below but I'm not sure how to go from there.

```
<% @sections.each do |section| %>
  <% Book.each do |book| %>
     <%= book.name %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Any help would be very appreciated!**

Comment: does a book have to have a section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need migration and associations between these models

```
change_table :books do |t|
  t.belongs_to :section, foreign_key: true, null: false
end
```

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :section

class Section < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
```

And in view you can iterate through sections and separately through evert section books

```
<% @sections.each do |section| %>
  <div><b><%= section.name %></b></div>

  <ul>
    <% section.books.each do |book| %>
      <li>
        <%= book.name %>, <%= book.author %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it not possible to keep book and section as one class? do they have to be separated with associations between the two?

Comment: There is [self-joining association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins)

Answer (score -1):

what you need is this:

```rb
<% @sections.each do |section| %>
  <% section.books.each do |book| %>
     <%= book.name %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```